# Installing a software without admin privileges via Regedit

Tags: windows, installation, regedit

I want to install an application which is installing in `AppData` folder. Normally, they do not need admin rights but still my application is asking for permission. This is an Excel Add-In exe file.

I have tried by using a bypass method, by adding a batch file.. All these did not work for this. I can`t change the privileges of a machine and I need to do modification for the setup only.

Now I`m trying to install this via `regedit`. I want to add a batch file to the setup. Anyone know how to do this?